# Emacs: where is better have the executable file?

Tags: emacs, path, debian

After many changes on my Debian Jessie, when I launch the command `emacs` I receive an error `libgnutls.so.26 : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.
If I launch instead the command `emacs24` everything is allright.

I have `emacs` in `/usr/local/bin`

I have `emacs24` in `/usr/bin`.

So, for now I created an alias to launch **emacs24** as *emacs*, but i don't like and, for example, i have to change the git setting to open the default ide cause **emacs** is not availlable yet.

The question is where is the correct position of the command ? I have to change my *PATH* ?
Consider that libgnutls.so.26 is not installable from apt.

Thanks for any suggest or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very strange, because a simple `sudo dnf install emacs` should suffice (I use fedora, so you probably use `apt-get` instead of `dnf`). Maybe it is best to just reinstall emacs (backup your .emacs to be safe) using `apt-get`? Anyhow, in fedora the emacs executable is located at `/usr/bin/emacs` (which is also the one used in the terminal when you use the emacs command).

Comment: I reinstalled emacs from `apt` and I run `emacs24` but not `emacs` command.
Is it possibile that the executable is putted in a different location if you installed from `.deb` (or `.dpkg`) or from `apt` ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, you may check the `/opt` folder. Why do you use the `emacs24` command instead of the `emacs` command?

Comment: I really don't know about this. I'll take a look at /opt folder and I'll let u know

Comment: I solved!
I purge ALL emacs and manually deleted the file installed by the .dpgk, updated the source list and re-install emacs. Now it works.
Thanks for answer by the way!